# Force download through markup or JS

Tags: javascript, http, html

Lets assume I have a file on a CDN (Cloud Files from Rackspace) and a static html page with a link to that file. Is there any way I can force download this file (to prevent it from opening in the browser -- for mp3s for example)?

We could make our server read the file and set the corresponding header to:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download")
```

but we have about 5 million downloads per month so we would rather let the CDN take care of that.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no `application/force-download`. Use `application/octet-stream` instead.

Comment: Thanks, now that I think about it the question doesn't make sense. There is no way a browser would let me define which file is to be saved and which isn't unless I have access to the headers.

Comment: Trying to force downloading by using the content-type is a hack. Use Content-Disposition instead.

Comment: Ah, but the Content-Type hack should be applicable to <a href="something" type="application/octet-stream">, right?

Comment: @Christopher: no. `type` on a link is advisory only, not an override; when the link is actually followed, the browser must use the real `Content-Type`. (There would be security problems, otherwise.) Currently no browsers do anything with `<a type>`.

Comment: @bobince: I take your word for it that currently no browsers react to `<a type>`, but: The browser *must* use the real Content-Type? Does that mean I can start serving `im_really_a_gif.txt` and expect browsers like, say IE to treat them properly once I send `Content-Type: image/gif` with it?

Comment: Ah, okay. Well yeah... that's a different issue. :-) Though in standards terms browsers ‘must’ use the real Content-Type over an advisory, IE has its own content sniffing disaster, which indeed also causes dire security problems. It can be told not to in IE8, though. However, your GIF-as-image/gif-with-.txt should work nonetheless, as the mime header and the actual content agree (the file extension is not normally of importance).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>There’s no way to do this in HTML or JavaScript.</del> [There is now! (Ish. See @BruceAldrige’s answer below.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14802816/20578)

The HTTP `Content-Disposition` header is what tells browsers to download the files, and that’s sent by the server. You have to configure the CDN to send that header with whichever files you want to browser to download instead of display.

Unhelpfully, I’m entirely unfamiliar with Rackspace’s Cloud Files service, so I don’t know if they allow this, nor how to do it. Just found a page from December 2009 that suggests not thought, sadly:

> Cloud Files cannot serve a file with the 'Content-Disposition: attachment' HTTP header. Therefore, a download link that would work perfectly in any other service may result in the browser rendering the file directly. This was confirmed by Rackspace engineers. :-(
>
> http://drupal.org/node/656714

I know that you can with Amazon’s CloudFront service, as it’s backed by S3 (see e.g. http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2009/06/how-to-set-custom-http-headers-for.html)

Comment: Yep, it's too late for us to move to S3 now. Thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the download attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download):

```
<a href="http..." download></a>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11024735/21460

However, [it’s not currently supported by Safari (7) or IE (11)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this through the cloudfiles API.  Using the method stream allows you to stream the contents of files in - setting your own headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

A crazy idea: download via XMLHttpRequest and serve a `data:` URL with the content type you want? :P