# How do I force download with HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: html, http, file, download, response

I have a link and, if a user clicks it, I need 2 things to happen:

- A proper HTTP response is sent to the user (especially with `Content-Type: video/mp4`)
- and a video file will automatically begin downloading.

I have seen something of the sort with PHP, but is it possible only with HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Automatically* will depend a lot on the browser and its options. But you can tell the browser what you *want* to have happen (which it will then double-check with the user) via the [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header in the response. For instance, setting it to `attachment;filename=blah.mp4` will, on most browsers, invite the user to download it (using that filename) even if normally the browser would have tried to display/play the content in its own interface. See the link for details. (Downloading is probably the default for mp4 files, but that's up to the user; I find this helpful when offering download links for HTML files.)

You can set the header via configuration in your web server if you're not using server-side scripting (as you've said you're not). For instance, with Apache you'd use a rule matching the URL for these video files and use the [`Header` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header).

Comment: (This is -- or at least, *was* -- not a duplicate answer. [I hate duplicate answers.] David edited his answer to include `Content-Disposition` *after* I posted mine about it.)

Comment: @David: I should have been clear that I wasn't criticizing. It's perfectly acceptable to improve one's answer. Just noting lest duplicate-answer fascists come after me. :-)

Answer (score 45):

you can use the download attribute

```
<a href="http..." download></a>
```

or specify a filename using

```
<a href="http..." download="filename.pdf"></a>
```

see more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/a#attr-download

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible (at least for values of JavaScript limited to client-side JavaScript).

If you want to override the default behavior of how a browser handles an HTTP resource, you need to do it with HTTP headers. If you want to do it correctly, use [the content-disposition header](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) (with an attachment value).

You can set this header using [server-side JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) or (pretty much) any other server side environment.

Answer (score 1):

I [found](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript/) a reliable way of forcing a download using the library [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
<script>
    let downloadUrl  = 'https://example.com/image.jpg';
    let downloadName = 'image.jpg';
    function download(){
        axios({
            url: downloadUrl,
            method:'GET',
            responseType: 'blob'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', downloadName);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        });
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: I’ve got the following error in Firefox: *Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at …*