# Download img created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, image, on-the-fly

I create img element with a jquery plugin.

I would like  to be able to click a button element and dowload the img element.

Is it possible without HTML5?

I do not store the image, cause it is created on the fly by jquery.

i'm using this plugin to create the img: http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/jquery.uqr/demo/

Comment: Why does this read like a haiku?

Comment: how is it created by jquery ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/jquery.uqr/demo/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2295455/309483 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/246801/309483

Comment: video and php i think they doesn't are what i'm searching for , anyway thx

Comment: Not possible without a server-side technology.

Comment: i'm thinking about triggering browser save dialog :P what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is from a different domain, you won't be able to access image contents, unless you try to use CORS - and even then, there's very limited browser support. Use [this plugin instead](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) and then [use toDataURL()](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html) to save it.

Comment: now i have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804428/dataimage-not-saving-as-image-on-mac-pc#comment17316182_12804428 :(

Answer (score 1):

The plugin you linked is using Google's deprecated [Image Charts portion of Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/). Since the images come from a remote server, you can't access them (from JavaScript. Of course you can load them) from your domain (it would be a form of XSS). You can make a PHP script to download a chart and change the Content-Type. When the client requests a PHP script that returns a document with Content-Type application/octet-stream, the download will commence.