# Canavas2Image.js save base64 img as png via element click

Tags: javascript, html, image, stream, base64

I'm unsing the canvas2Image.js plugin:

```
/*
 * Canvas2Image v0.1
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Jacob Seidelin, jseidelin@nihilogic.dk
 * MIT License [http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php]
 */

var Canvas2Image = (function() {

    // check if we have canvas support
    var bHasCanvas = false;
    var oCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    if (oCanvas.getContext("2d")) {
        bHasCanvas = true;
    }

    // no canvas, bail out.
    if (!bHasCanvas) {
        return {
            saveAsBMP : function(){},
            saveAsPNG : function(){},
            saveAsJPEG : function(){}
        }
    }

    var bHasImageData = !!(oCanvas.getContext("2d").getImageData);
    var bHasDataURL = !!(oCanvas.toDataURL);
    var bHasBase64 = !!(window.btoa);

    var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";

    // ok, we're good
    var readCanvasData = function(oCanvas) {
        var iWidth = parseInt(oCanvas.width);
        var iHeight = parseInt(oCanvas.height);
        return oCanvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,iWidth,iHeight);
    }

    // base64 encodes either a string or an array of charcodes
    var encodeData = function(data) {
        var strData = "";
        if (typeof data == "string") {
            strData = data;
        } else {
            var aData = data;
            for (var i=0;i<aData.length;i++) {
                strData += String.fromCharCode(aData[i]);
            }
        }
        return btoa(strData);
    }

    // creates a base64 encoded string containing BMP data
    // takes an imagedata object as argument
    /*var createBMP = function(oData) {
        var aHeader = [];

        var iWidth = oData.width;
        var iHeight = oData.height;

        aHeader.push(0x42); // magic 1
        aHeader.push(0x4D); 

        var iFileSize = iWidth*iHeight*3 + 54; // total header size = 54 bytes
        aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
        aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
        aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256); iFileSize = Math.floor(iFileSize / 256);
        aHeader.push(iFileSize % 256);

        aHeader.push(0); // reserved
        aHeader.push(0);
        aHeader.push(0); // reserved
        aHeader.push(0);

        aHeader.push(54); // dataoffset
        aHeader.push(0);
        aHeader.push(0);
        aHeader.push(0);

        var aInfoHeader = [];
        aInfoHeader.push(40); // info header size
        aInfoHeader.push(0);
        aInfoHeader.push(0);
        aInfoHeader.push(0);

        var iImageWidth = iWidth;
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256); iImageWidth = Math.floor(iImageWidth / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageWidth % 256);

        var iImageHeight = iHeight;
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256); iImageHeight = Math.floor(iImageHeight / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iImageHeight % 256);

        aInfoHeader.push(1); // num of planes
        aInfoHeader.push(0);

        aInfoHeader.push(24); // num of bits per pixel
        aInfoHeader.push(0);

        aInfoHeader.push(0); // compression = none
        aInfoHeader.push(0);
        aInfoHeader.push(0);
        aInfoHeader.push(0);

        var iDataSize = iWidth*iHeight*3; 
        aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); iDataSize = Math.floor(iDataSize / 256);
        aInfoHeader.push(iDataSize % 256); 

        for (var i=0;i<16;i++) {
            aInfoHeader.push(0);    // these bytes not used
        }

        var iPadding = (4 - ((iWidth * 3) % 4)) % 4;

        var aImgData = oData.data;

        var strPixelData = "";
        var y = iHeight;
        do {
            var iOffsetY = iWidth*(y-1)*4;
            var strPixelRow = "";
            for (var x=0;x<iWidth;x++) {
                var iOffsetX = 4*x;

                strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX+2]);
                strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX+1]);
                strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(aImgData[iOffsetY+iOffsetX]);
            }
            for (var c=0;c<iPadding;c++) {
                strPixelRow += String.fromCharCode(0);
            }
            strPixelData += strPixelRow;
        } while (--y);

        var strEncoded = encodeData(aHeader.concat(aInfoHeader)) + encodeData(strPixelData);

        return strEncoded;
    }
*/

    // sends the generated file to the client
    var saveFile = function(strData) {
        document.location.href = strData;
    }

    var makeDataURI = function(strData, strMime) {
        return "data:" + strMime + ";base64," + strData;
    }

    // generates a <img> object containing the imagedata
    var makeImageObject = function(strSource) {
        var oImgElement = document.createElement("img");
        oImgElement.src = strSource;
        return oImgElement;
    }

    var scaleCanvas = function(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight) {
        if (iWidth && iHeight) {
            var oSaveCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            oSaveCanvas.width = iWidth;
            oSaveCanvas.height = iHeight;
            oSaveCanvas.style.width = iWidth+"px";
            oSaveCanvas.style.height = iHeight+"px";

            var oSaveCtx = oSaveCanvas.getContext("2d");

            oSaveCtx.drawImage(oCanvas, 0, 0, oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
            return oSaveCanvas;
        }
        return oCanvas;
    }

    return {

        saveAsPNG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
            if (!bHasDataURL) {
                return false;
            }
            var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
            var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            if (bReturnImg) {
                return makeImageObject(strData);
            } else {
                saveFile(strData.replace("image/png", strDownloadMime));
            }
            return true;
        },

        saveAsJPEG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
            if (!bHasDataURL) {
                return false;
            }

            var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
            var strMime = "image/jpeg";
            var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL(strMime);

            // check if browser actually supports jpeg by looking for the mime type in the data uri.
            // if not, return false
            if (strData.indexOf(strMime) != 5) {
                return false;
            }

            if (bReturnImg) {
                return makeImageObject(strData);
            } else {
                saveFile(strData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime));
            }
            return true;
        },

    /*  saveAsBMP : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
            if (!(bHasImageData && bHasBase64)) {
                return false;
            }

            var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);

            var oData = readCanvasData(oScaledCanvas);
            var strImgData = createBMP(oData);
            if (bReturnImg) {
                return makeImageObject(makeDataURI(strImgData, "image/bmp"));
            } else {
                saveFile(makeDataURI(strImgData, strDownloadMime));
            }
            return true;
        }*/
    };

})();
```

in html i do:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var _txt = "hey";
    $('#qrcode').qrcode({
      text  :_txt
    });
    $("#qrcode-canvas").attr("download","file.png");
    var oCanvas = document.getElementById("qrcode-canvas");  
    $("#download-qrcode").on('click',function(){
      Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
    })
  });
  </script>

<div id="qrcode" class="" style="" ></div>
 <a class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" id="download-qrcode"><i class="icon icon-download-alt icon-white"></i> download</a>
```

I'm having problem, i'm using macosx FF,Chrome Opera and Safari, then i call the saveAsPNG() method via element click

The image returns a document without extension to be saved:

```
data:image/octet-stream;base64,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
```

I would like to save it as image, would like png :/

is that possible?

cause i kow i can fix that using data:image/png;etc.. but it will open new window in browser.

Comment: If you don't give it a correct MIME type, how is it supposed to know what type of image file to save it as?

Comment: i mean if i do image/png it opens new window while image/octet-stream not and i don't want to open new window

Comment: @Barmar sorry i didn't tagged you on comment

Comment: What kind of element is the data in? I'm mostly familiar with using it in `<IMG>`, so it just displays right there in the page, it doesn't download or open a new window.

Comment: I can do it in Chrome if it helps.

Comment: Or you can have a PHP file to bounce off to make it download with a filename if you want..? Or you can use htaccess to give it a filename..? Let me know

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @nick_w done sorry  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this question: [Name a PNG file saved from Canvas using an "open with" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045603/name-a-png-file-saved-from-canvas-using-an-open-with-dialog), you can use the `download` attribute of an `a` element to indicate that the `href` should be downloaded with the given name.

Better still, we can set the `href` to the return value of `toDataURL` which will ensure the image is in fact downloaded as a PNG.

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-inverse" id="download-qrcode" download="my_file.png">
    <i class="icon icon-download-alt icon-white"></i>
    download
</a>

$("#download-qrcode").on('click',function(){
    var dataUrl = oCanvas[0].toDataURL();
    $(this).attr('href', dataUrl);
});
```

When the link is clicked, the file will be downloaded as `my_file.png`. As stated in that question, the `download` attribute is not that widely supported - the above code only worked in Chrome even though Firefox apparently supports that attribute.

I'm not really sure how to work around this as you can't set a `Content-Disposition` in a `data:` URL, which means that you can't force the download like you can with a server-side.

You could also check out this: http://www.joeltrost.com/blog/2012/01/29/html5-canvas-save-a-jpeg-with-extension/, which deals with the same problem using a post-back approach. The nice thing with this is that it takes advatage of the server's ability to specify the `Content-Disposition` so you can force the image to be downloaded.

**Edit:**

So the idea of the post-back approach is basically to send the data Url back to the server which essentially echos it back. The trick is that when doing so, a `Content-Disposition` is set, forcing the image to be downloaded.

Now the link shows a solution in PHP, so you could probably reuse the script to do the same thing.

Comment: not catched at all sorry, does the href attr makes me able to download the file as an image? or are you suggesting an ajax call to download the image?

Comment: using your code when clicking to download the browser open a new tab showing the image in PNG format, which is quite a big step foward, may i need to use an ajax call to that url so i can receive the file to download back?

Comment: i mean, i can send an xhr request sending the base64 img code to  a little php script that it (maybe) saves the img and makes me download that...

Comment: I'm surprised it opened in a new tab. When I ran my code, it simply downloaded to disk (in Chrome), while in FF (and possibly IE) it just opened the image.

Comment: ok tryed both on CH and in FF and it opens the image in a new tab, i'm really thinking on getting the image via server side script ajax :P

Comment: Interesting. I think the server-side approach is the way to go to get something that will be cross-browser compatible. Besides, it should be reasonably easy to implement.