# Code that gets image src's from web page

Tags: javascript, image

I have a problem with this code:

```
   var someStr = "";
    var txtBox=document.createElement("textarea");
    for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {           
           var a=document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i];
           var urll = a.getAttribute("src");
           someStr += "\n" + urll;
    }
    document.body.appendChild(txtBox).innerHTML = someStr;
```

I'm trying to make a script that grabs all the image src from given webpage and just lists them. Then by other already done code, I'm going to download them. By `[i]` I'm trying to move to the next image with every loop, but it gives me 10 times the same image. Any ideas?

P.S: Thanks for the quick responses!!!

Any idea from someone how can I download the images in the array using js? I know hot to do it in c#, c++, VB.net, but I dont want to make the user to download any software. I can't think of any easy way to do it with js since it have to work on different sites. Any ideas? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/d9TsH/

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but the order of the elements included to a NodeList produced by `getElementsByTagName()` is not guaranteed to be the same as `img`s appear on the page. You can try to move definition of `a` outiside of the loop. Also make sure you really have 10 different `src`s at the time when this loop is executed.

Comment: Well, I'm trying it on this page: http://fullhdpics.tumblr.com/ . It has only 10 images per page, that's why the for loop is like that. But it keeps returning me 10 times the same src. Thanks for the quick response. @Teemu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try adding all the sources to an array

```
var array = new Array();
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
array.push(images[i].src);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is working. It's not working on the site that i provided, but I guess, that Tumblr is somehow denying this. It is working on other websites, which is good. Thank you very much

Comment: There's no practical difference between this and the original code; if this works, then the original code works too.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea from someone how can I download the images in the array using js? I know hot to do it in c#, c++, VB.net, but I dont want to make the user to download any software. I can't think of any easy way to do it since it have to work on different sites. Any ideas? I would really appreciate it.@Juhana

Comment: if you mean have the client download, you can take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295455/how-do-i-force-download-with-html-javascript/11024735#11024735

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Thank you VERY much. I spend so much time to think and find some way to do it via JS. Thanks again.