# Ajax request get file through post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Ajax post request which might receive static file in response, but i don't know how to show that file to the client.i mean something like download function through post request.

here is my sample ajax request:

```
function Getfile(id)
                {
                var mhost='http://myhost/post';
                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: mhost,
                  data: { task: 'getfile', id: myid },
                  beforeSend:function(){
                    // this is where we append a loading image

                  },
                  success:function(data){
                    // successful request; how to show file to the user for download?
                  },
                  error:function(){
                    // failed request; give feedback to user

                  }
                });

                }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a js fiddle or specify where you want to display the data. is it a page or column. and the you are trying to do should be done using GET method not post.

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: simply you can redirect the user to full path of file at your your success function

Comment: i should do it using post, i want to save the file with or without user interaction

Comment: the file is static like txt or pdf.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to treat them both as any other html and show it in the browser;

```
success:function(data){
    // successful request; how to show file to the user for download?                  },
    location.href = data;
```

For PDF, users who has a PDF viewer will likely see it straight and users who don't will get a download request.

For TXT, most user will likely see it straight and the rest will get a download request.

The action taken by their browser depends on the browser settings.

You can do it in another way though, using content-headers. This link has more info about that: [How do I force download with HTML/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295455/how-do-i-force-download-with-html-javascript)

This also means that you force something else on the user, that they might not like.

A third approach could be offering them a choice, whether to download or read it online.