# Downloading a .wav or .mp3 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, download, wav

I need to have a link on my website page download a sound file. I know that if you direct a link to say, a .doc file it will open a blank page and download the file (because the browser can't read the file), but that does not work with sound files- they are opened with a media player in the browser. How can I automatically download this file instead of opening it in-browser?

This is in Chrome, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I think the server must send the file with header: Content-Disposition: attachment;

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295455/how-do-i-force-download-with-html-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176302/force-download-through-markup-or-js

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href='file.mp3' download='Very-Very-Good.mp3'>download</a>
```

Comment: It's not javascript

Answer (score -3):

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('song.mp3')">DownLoad Song</a>
```